# Conditional distributions of multivariate normal

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value, density-function

I'm struggling with this exercise:

Suppose the density of $(X,Y)'$ is given by
$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp({-\frac{1}{2}(x^2-2xy+2y^2)})$.
Determine the conditional distributions, particularly the conditional expectations and the conditional variances.

I saw the solutions and it's said that $EX=EY=0$. It may be silly but can't get why. Moreover, the solutions show $\Lambda^{-1}$ but how can i find it?

Comment: I'm guessing $\Lambda$ is the inverse of the covariance matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\-1&2\end{pmatrix}$. The density is written for $\mathbf x:=(x,y)$ as $f(\mathbf x)={\mathrm e}^{-\frac12(\mathbf x-\mathbf\mu)^T\Lambda^{-1}(\mathbf x-\mathbf\mu)}/(2\pi\sqrt{|\Lambda|})$, with a zero mean-vector $\mathbf\mu$, so $EX=EY=0$.

Comment: and how do you say mean vector is null?

Comment: There is no linear term in the quadratic form.